# How to validate a table in Rails using another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, associations, model-associations

Using Ruby associations, I have two models that are associated to each other

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to  :post
```

and

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :event
```

The Post table has a boolean column titled :anon. I want to create a validation when trying to create an event. If the anon field is true then the associated event is valid, otherwise an event is not valid.
Is there a way I can do this using Rails associations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [before_create](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback here, for this purpose, something like following:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :event
before_save :validate_event

def validate_event
  anon ? event.valid : event.invalid  
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked exacly how I wanted it too. Just had to change the event.valid :  event.invalid to event.save : !event.save

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

**Post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :event

before_save :validate_event

def validate_event
     if self.anon == true
         validates :event, presence: true
     end
end
```

I didn't test this but hope it will work ..

Answer (score 0):

First, your association needs to be corrected.

You have `belongs_to` on both sides of relationship; while in contrary, you should use `has_one` or `has_many` at one side depending on the type of association you wish to achieve.
Read more about [association basics.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

You can then use [`validates_associated`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated) in `Event` to validate the associated `post`, or create a custom `before_save` hook to do that.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  before_create :validate_post


  private
  def validate_post
    #since it is boolean, it will return `true` or `false`,
    #If false, validation will fail, else pass
    post.anon 
  end
end
```